# Free UML plugin for Eclipse Indigo (3.7)?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, uml

Yes, now I need a free UML plugin for Eclipse Indigo. Someone can help me ?

Comment: For what purpose do you need a UML plugin? There are several, and answers would vary on what you intend to do with the plugin. Besides, there have been quite a few questions asked about this in the past, and most of the answers continue to hold good. Asking another question might be pointless.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse+uml

Answer (score 1):

Papyrus or Topcased are free and open source. Soyatec is not free, not open source and the free license goal is only to push you to buy the studio edition.

Answer (score 0):

I would try [Soyatec's eUML2](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/installation/) plugin. I've had good success with that, and it offers an Evaluation license (i.e., no use in commercial software). The installation page only shows that it works up to Eclipse 3.6, though if you give it a shot, it might just work in 3.7 (I've had that happen for other plugins, so you could just give it a shot)

Comment: Depends on what you want. Look at the features page on their site. It shows the differences between the two editions.

"eUML2 Free Edition gathers all basic features needed by java developpers and is free of use (even for commercial purposes)". That is one interesting thing to note about the Free edition.

Comment: studio edition need money ? I install and don't see any key/register popup !

Comment: From their site regarding the pricing, "An Evaluation license file is bundled within the Studio Edition available on the update site. This evaluation license enables all features of eUML2 Studio Edition but it must only be used for evaluation without any commercial purpose".

So basically you are using it as an evaluation, for which you then make the purchase so you can use it in commercial products.